# How to fix `Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation` error?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to do SSO authentication with puppeteer. The URL redirects to original page after login. I would like to grab content of the page after login completes and page is fully loaded. I'm getting 
`Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation` error. Which execution context was destroyed? how can I get page's content after redirection?

```js
/*
Get reponse for a URL
 */
let getPageResponse = async function (url, cookies, timeout) {
    try {

        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        const response = await page.goto(url, {'timeout': timeout, 'waitUntil': ['load', 'networkidle0']});
        let currentUrl = page.url();

        await page.type("#uname", secrets.id);
        await page.type("#pwd", secrets.password);
        let [responseNew] = await Promise.all([
            page.waitForNavigation({'timeout': 30000, 'waitUntil': ['load', 'networkidle0']}),
            page.click(handleInfo.element),
        ]);

        let content = await page.content();

        console.log("<<"+content);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('<<<<< ERROR' + e);
    } finally {
    }
```

Comment: What do you have in the `handleInfo.element`?

Comment: There is a button selector.

Comment: Seems things work okay If I add more explicit  wait before "await page.content()".